# store procedure return multiple data sets how to access all data sets in telerik report designer

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, telerik

I'm using telerik report and stuck in following problem. I have store procedure which return following data(see result 1). But same store procedure result are not same as of result 1 when view in telerik report designer. I don't know why . I have searched but didn't find any thing.

Actual Result of store procedure.

[image: Result 1]

Same store procedure result in Telerik report designer.

[image: Result 2]